# Why my inline-flex elements are not displaying inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

I'm trying to build a custom element menu component. I'd like to be able to make the menu items either vertically or horizontally oriented. Main menu items display correctly (=horizontally) in my example. But for some reason my sub menu items get vertically oriented even though they should be displayed as inline-flex too.

[Example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/jutunen/pen/eYmOwNB)

```css
.item, .heading {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Why are my menu items oriented differently?

Comment: There's no room for them to spread out horizontally.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ok, if I remove the width definition from CSS and change the text 'Sub menu' to something much longer, I get the correct orientation for the sub menu items. But why are the main menu items correctly oriented in the first place?

Comment: Problem solved when I change line 54 to this: `this.itemsContainer.style.display = 'flex'`